# spawn php ENOENT when using XDebug in VSCode

Tags: php, windows-subsystem-for-linux, xdebug

VSCode 1.25 version, XDebug 2.6, php-fpm 72, Windows 10 (1803).

I have installed xdebug itself and vscode xdebug extension using this info: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=felixfbecker.php-debug

Now when i run debugger, i immediately get an error in a DEBUG console:

`spawn php ENOENT`

Despite this thing - everything seems to be working (debugging itself) as intended. Should i ignore this message/error?

I am using php inside WSL, in VSCode (installed in Windows) settings i've set correct (working) path to my php.

Comment: Vscode in Windows or in Linux?

Comment: in Windows, php is inside WSL

Comment: Voting to migrate this to Stack Overflow.

Comment: I need it in Windows. so no way.